How do I get this $Q(x,y)$ into a sum of squares without matrices
The bivariate quadratic polynomial $Q(x,y)$ is:
$$Q(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy-a(2x+y)$$
to get it into a sum of squares, is there a method without any rotation of matrices involved?  I can kind of can get it to this:
$$Q(x,y)=(x+a)^2-a^2+y(x-a)+y^2=\hat{x}^2+\hat{x}\hat{y}+\hat{y}^2-a^2$$ using $\hat{x}=x+a$ and $\hat{y}=y$, but I can't seem to get further to the sum of squares. If there is no other option than to use a rotation, can someone enlighten me on that process? If it is possible too I could ask for a good link/resource to learn it.

I'm confused by the notation $Q(x,y)$ which is a quadratic form only if $a$ is included in the variables.  [See the tag info for [tag:quadratic-forms]].

Indeed, a quadratic form is supposed to be homogeneous in $x$ and $y$. I think the post is about finding a coordinate transformation to $x',y'$ which makes this into an actual quadratic form. Is this correct?

@hardmath my bad I remember very little of algebra, it is just a quantum physics problem that I got in which I need to put it into a sum of squares, I don't know if it is a form or not. $a$ is just a constant

@AnCar maybe I should just remove the "quadratic form" term, $a$ is just a constant

For some constants $a$ it will not be possible.  A sum of squares of real numbers (you should clarify what domain $Q(x,y)$ has) will be non-negative.  So if $a=2$ one gets $Q(1,1) = 3 - 2(3) < 0$ and it is not possible.

@hardmath so the only way will be with a rotation involving matrices, and how can I do so?

That's not my point.  It is impossible to write $Q(x,y)$ as a  sum of squares when $a=2$ (or larger) because a sum of squares is always non-negative on real arguments.  This fails in my example because $Q(1,1) = -3$.  What do you know about the constant $a$?

One version :  $ (x + \frac{y}{2} - a)^2 + \frac{3}{4} y^2 - a^2  $

@Ivy Can you be more specific with what it is that you are looking for exactly? Do you want to find variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $Q(x,y)=X^2+Y^2$? Are you working over $\mathbb{R}$  or $\mathbb{C}$?

@AnCar it is quantum mechanics problem so I'm guessing over C, but I don't know, it comes from trying to get a potential of the form $V(x,y)=Q$ (that quadratic form) into a sum of squares to use the $\frac12 kx^2$ to find the energy

@hardmath really nothing, it says it is a distance $a$, so I'm guessing it's non-negative

The issue is it's really not clear what you want to do here. Over $\mathbb{C}$, anything can be written as a sum of arbitrarily many squares, e.g., $re^{i\phi}=0^2+0^2+\dots+0^2+\big(\sqrt{r}e^{i\phi/2}\big)^2$.

The existence of the $xy$ term means you have to have some term that multiplies $x$ and $y$ together, meaning that if you're trying to write it as the sum of squares of linear expressions that at least one of them will include both $x$ and $y$, which I think is equivalent to what you're calling "rotation of matrices".
For example, one way to approach this expression would be as:
$$\begin{eqnarray} x^2 + y^2 + xy - a(2x + y) & = & x^2 + (y - 2a)x + y^2 - ay \\
& = & \left(x + \frac{1}{2}y - a\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{2}y - a\right)^2 + y^2 - ay \\
& = & \left(x + \frac{1}{2}y - a\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}y^2 - a^2
\end{eqnarray}$$
Even with your $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ version, the cross-term $\hat{x}\hat{y}$ can't be removed without rotating the basis, but at least you've got a quadratic form that you can work with.
